# Не срабатывает переопределяемый стиль CSS

Tags: html, css, переопределение

Есть размеченная html-страница. В файле стилей для обрамляющего блока указываю изначальный размер шрифта. Потом в одном из вложенных элементов пытаюсь размер шрифта изменить. Но этого не происходит! Хотя в своем файле стилей - объявление размера шрифта вложенного элемента происходит после определений обрамляющего блока. `Vivaldi` показывает это вот так:

[image: скриншот]

Выход из положения: добавляю `!important` в определение размера шрифта для вложенного элемента, тогда все работает как надо.

**Вопрос:** почему так происходит, и можно ли обойтись без `!important`?

PS. Мой файл стилей в странице определен последним, если что.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Специфичность](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) селектора `#page-content p` выше, чем у селектора `.room-card-text`.

Поэтому, даже если это правило с двумя компонентами в селекторе (здесь это id и тип) определено в CSS раньше, выше правила с одним компонентом в селекторе - все равно имеет более высокий приоритет, и не перекрывается.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Про селекторы то я и забыл.

Comment: @Николай, польза ответа определяется его конкретикой и достаточной для понимания полнотой содержимого. Сейчас я отредактировал твой ответ вместо того чтобы просто влепить ему минус (как некоторые тут делают, и в этом они _правы_), но в будущем пиши подробнее, пожалуйста.